# Get HashMap with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap

```
public class First {
    public final static Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        MAP.put("A", "1");
        MAP.put("B", "2");
    }
}

public class Second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("First");
        Field field = clazz.getField("MAP");
        Map<String, String> newMap = (HashMap<String, String>) field.get(null); // Obviously doesn't work
    }
}
```

Pretty much it. I have no trouble getting for example values of String variables, but I'm stuck with this one. Tryed to google it, failed. Also, if possible I'd like to get this Map without instantiating its class.

Comment: "`// Obviously doesn't work`"  - Please include the compilation errors in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is to handle the exceptions for:

- Class.forName("First");
- clazz.getField("MAP");
- field.get(null);

The code below get the static map field from First class. Here I'm just throwing/propagating the exceptions in the main method but you should handle the exceptions in a try/catch block accordingly.

```
class First {
  public final static Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    MAP.put("A", "1");
    MAP.put("B", "2");
  }
}


public class Second {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
      ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("First");
    Field field = clazz.getField("MAP");
    Map<String, String> newMap = (HashMap<String, String>) field.get(null); // Obviously doesn't work
    System.out.println(newMap); //Prints {A=1, B=2}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, turns out, I've just had a weird IDEA lag. Relaunched it and everything works now. Exceptions were there, I've just forgot to write them (having troubles with copy pasting stuff here)

Answer (score 1):

Here the same example with a non static class:

```
package at.noe.szb;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ReflectionTest {
    private class First {
        public Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>();
        First(){
            MAP.put("A", "1");
            MAP.put("B", "2");
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testMap() throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("at.noe.szb.First");
        Field field = clazz.getField("MAP");
        Map<String, String> newMap = (HashMap<String, String>) field.get(clazz);
        assertEquals("{A=1, B=2}", newMap.toString());
    }
}
```